# Requests Operation is not working on Raw PHP

Tags: php, request

I have been trying to implement calling the specific API from the API I created. **It is raw PHP, no framework is being used. Just a normal php file**. Since I know that I have implemented the code right and tested few things on MAMP server, but the problem is **Every time I try to call the API, I get 500 Internal Server Error**.

I have downloaded the **Requests.php** file from this script from git: `git clone git://github.com/rmccue/Requests.git`

The file path is defined correct since I have reverified it.

Possibility is Request file is not getting implemented. Have included the Request file in my php file.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    include('Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php');
    $response = array();
    $request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    if( $request_method == 'GET' ){
        Requests::register_autoloader();
        $response = Requests::get('https://nut-case.s3.amazonaws.com/jobs.json');
        echo $response;
    }else {
        echo 'No defined function for this method. Please use GET only';
    }
?>
```

**PHP Error Logs**

```
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php(177): Requests_Transport_cURL->process_response('{"data":[{"_id"...', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(379): Requests_Transport_cURL->request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(231): Requests::request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/index.php(29): Requests::get('https://nut-cas...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php on line 422
[07-Jan-2020 13:26:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Requests_Exception: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 1131134 out of 1459668 bytes received in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php:422
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php(177): Requests_Transport_cURL->process_response('{"data":[{"_id"...', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(379): Requests_Transport_cURL->request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(231): Requests::request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/index.php(29): Requests::get('https://nut-cas...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php on line 422
[07-Jan-2020 13:27:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Requests_Exception: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 1113726 out of 1459668 bytes received in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php:422
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php(177): Requests_Transport_cURL->process_response('{"data":[{"_id"...', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(379): Requests_Transport_cURL->request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(231): Requests::request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/index.php(29): Requests::get('https://nut-cas...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php on line 422
[07-Jan-2020 13:28:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Requests_Exception: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 1096318 out of 1459668 bytes received in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php:422
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php(177): Requests_Transport_cURL->process_response('{"data":[{"_id"...', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(379): Requests_Transport_cURL->request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(231): Requests::request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/index.php(29): Requests::get('https://nut-cas...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php on line 422
[07-Jan-2020 13:28:16 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Requests_Exception: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 1113726 out of 1459668 bytes received in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php:422
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php(177): Requests_Transport_cURL->process_response('{"data":[{"_id"...', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(379): Requests_Transport_cURL->request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests.php(231): Requests::request('https://nut-cas...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/index.php(29): Requests::get('https://nut-cas...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php on line 422
```

The url is fine. I am trying my API on my localhost using MAMP, and the API is running fine. This is for testing purposes, since I am learning PHP for the first time. Please help. Thanks

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Your include path should start with a `/`, otherwise it will look for Applications in your current project folder.

Comment: Tried using `/` @aynber, same error. Could you help me out how. This is the only error in the console I see right now: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: That's in your browser console. You need to check your web server error logs, which is probably in `/Applications/MAMP/logs/`

Comment: Added error logs @aynber. Please see.

Comment: `cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 1113726 out of 1459668 bytes received `. You're making a connection, but it's taking longer than 10 seconds. There should be a way with that class to raise the timeout.

Comment: Any help you can provide @aynber?

Comment: You get a timeout error, the requested page is to big/ take to long. I see it use curl why do you use this instead of curl by your self? then you can extend easly the proccess limit time

Comment: You want me to use curl for making request in the PHP file @Baracuda078?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this to get the data.

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['phone_num'])) {

  if (trim($_POST['phone_num']) != '') {
    $ch = curl_init('https://nut-case.s3.amazonaws.com/jobs.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); // The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Check if the request has status 200 ok
    if ($httpStatus == 200) {
      var_dump(json_decode($data));
    } else {
      //return an error
    }
  } else {
    // return error invalid phone_num
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: I didnt test it in your case, but i use this in my projects and work fine. maybe you need to set other curl_setopt variables

Comment: Hey it works partially fine for this case. Could you please show me how to make this work for `POST` method. Thanks. I just have one `param` to pass that is `phone_num`. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: To execute this on a POST request is easy, but i dont understand what you whant with the param phone_num

Comment: It is just the POST method sometimes requires params too, so how to have that thing with POST operation, if that makes sense to you. I do have a param to pass in my POST url, that is `phone_num`.

Comment: I changed my answer, I think this is what you mean but im not sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205531/discussion-between-alok-and-baracuda078).

Comment: Could you please tell me the how you do the POST method operation, I will see what I can do for the data?

Comment: Create a simple html form with method="post" to trigger the function

Comment: Could you please show me that in your code. I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: stackoverflow is not to write the code for others, try it your self and try to debug it when it is not working. when you can't find the problem ask for help here on the forum